# Any Free source code for captcha images for asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

i am creating a registration form for that i want to implement the captcha image.can i get the source code or any reference.Thanking you

Comment: Not to throw water in the fire: I have use captcha for a few years but, recently, I have been pushed to try a different approach as users are complaining about the difficulty to resolve those "puzzles". I, myelf, have gotten really irritated with many sites I have to resolve it. EVEN HERE AT STACK OVERFLOW "I'M A HUMAN". I am developing a pin version of things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to use [reCAPTCHA](http://recaptcha.net/). It's free, widely used, and well documented. And by using it you'll be helping the project along digitizing old books.

They have code samples for asp.net [HERE](http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/aspnet.html)

Comment: hi Ira Rainey super dude it is working fine good reference it is so simple dude. give me reply for this

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/CaptchaControl.aspx) (first result of search string [asp.net captcha](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=asp.net+captcha&aq=f&oq=&aqi=g10)).